# Load spring beans from custom groovy files in grails app

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy, spring-dsl

Trying to load spring beans from custom groovy file in Grails `2.3.7.` I know this question has been asked before, but after hours of searching, I'm unable to find a consistent approach that loads from the classpath.

### The Goal

- Modularize `resources.groovy` into multiple custom resource files
- Put custom resource files in standard location: `grails-app/conf/spring`
- Use plugin to do the magic; minimize overhead

### Tried...

```
//## grails-app/conf/spring/MyBeansConfig.groovy 
beans {
   testsvc(TestService){
      msg = 'hello'
   }
}
```

Note above, I'm using `beans {}`, not `beans = {}`, [apparently](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/can-resources-groovy-be-referenced-as-in-Externalized-Configuration-td1390957.html) it makes a difference:

**resources.groovy**

This works...

```
beans = {
  loadBeans 'file:C:\\Proj\Test1\grails-app\\conf\\spring\\MyBeansConfig.groovy'
}
```

...and according to [docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/guide/spring.html#springdsl), this should too, but doesn't:

```
importBeans("classpath:*MyBeansConfig.groovy")
```

## UPDATE - WORKING OPTIONS

*(working for Grails 2.3.7)*

### Option 1: (src/java)

Following [lukelazarovic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24031582/791406) advice, this approach works since Grails automatically copies (not compiles) groovy files in `src/java` to the classpath; works fine in eclipse and with war deployment:

```
//bean config files here
src/java/MyBeansConfig.groovy
src/java/FooBeansConfig.groovy

//resources.groovy
loadBeans('classpath*:*BeansConfig.groovy')
```

### Options 2: (grails-app/conf/spring)

This approach allows for custom bean config files in `grails-app/conf/spring` (credits to  [ideascultor](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-Config-Location-not-working-on-Tomcat-tp4629703p4629706.html) and [mark.esher](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-Config-Location-not-working-on-Tomcat-tp4629703.html))

```
   //bean config files here
   grails-app/conf/spring/MyBeansConfig.groovy

   //## resources.groovy
   //for eclipse/local testing
   loadBeans('file:./grails-app/conf/spring/*BeansConfig.groovy')
   //for WAR/classpath 
   loadBeans('classpath*:*BeansConfig.groovy')


   //## BuildConfig.groovy
   grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
      copy(todir: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/classes/spring") {
         fileset(dir:"grails-app/conf/spring") {
            include(name: "*BeansConfig.groovy")
            exclude(name: "resources.groovy")        
            exclude(name: "resources.xml")
         }
      }
   }
```

### Options 3: (Custom Plugin)

If you're using custom plugins, this approach is ideal; boiler plate config gets refactored into the plugin:

**Plugin Config**

```
   //## scripts/_Events.groovy
   eventCreateWarStart = { warName, stagingDir ->
      def libDir = new File("${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/classes/spring")

      ant.copy(todir: libDir) {
         fileset(dir:"grails-app/conf/spring") {
            include(name: "*BeansConfig.groovy")
            exclude(name: "resources.groovy")
            exclude(name: "resources.xml")
         }
      }
   }

   //## MyGrailsPlugin.groovy
   def doWithSpring = {       
      loadBeans('file:./grails-app/conf/spring/*BeansConfig.groovy')
      loadBeans('classpath*:*BeansConfig.groovy') 
   }
```

**Grails App**

No config!...just create your bean config files using the `*BeansConfig.groovy` convention, good to go!

```
//bean config files here
grails-app/conf/spring/MyBeansConfig.groovy
```

## Update 9/24/2015

Found some issues with option 3:

- loading of duplicate resource files
- spring resources not configured correctly for `test-app`

We managed to fix the above issue such that any resource files in `grails-app/conf/spring` work the same when executing Grails in eclipse, WAR, test-app, etc.

First step: we created a class to have more control over locating and loading resource files; this was necessary as some files were being loaded more than once due to cross-referenced beans.
We're using a plugin to encapsulate this functionality, so this class lives in that plugin:

```
class CustomResourceLoader {
   static loadSpringBeans(BeanBuilder bb){         
         def files = ['*'] //load all resource files 
         //match resources using multiple methods
         def matchedResourceList = []
         files.each {
            matchedResourceList +=
               getPatternResolvedResources("file:./grails-app/conf/spring/" + it + ".groovy").toList()
            matchedResourceList +=
               getPathMatchedResources("classpath*:spring/" + it + ".groovy").toList()
         }

         //eliminate duplicates resource loaded from recursive reference
         def resourceMap = [:]       
         matchedResourceList.each{
            if(it) resourceMap.put(it.getFilename(), it) 
         }           
         //make resources.groovy first in list
         def resourcesFile = resourceMap.remove("resources.groovy")
         if(!resourcesFile)
            throw new RuntimeException("resources.groovy was not found where expected!")

         def resourcesToLoad = [resourcesFile]
         resourceMap.each{k,v -> resourcesToLoad << v }         
         log.debug("Spring resource files about to load: ")        
         resourcesToLoad.each{ bb.loadBeans(it) }
   }

   static def getPatternResolvedResources(path){
      ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver =
         new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
      return resourcePatternResolver.getResources(path);
   }

   static def getPathMatchedResources(path){
      return new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources(path)
   }
}
```

Removed `BeansConfig.groovy` suffix; WAR generation now picks up any resources in `grails-app/conf/spring`

```
plugin, _Events.groovy
eventCreateWarStart = { warName, stagingDir ->
      def libDir = new File("${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/classes/spring")
      ant.copy(todir: libDir) {
         fileset(dir:"grails-app/conf/spring") {
            include(name: "*.groovy")          
            exclude(name: "resources.xml")
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In the plugin definition file, call the loader from `doWithSpring()`, passing `BeanBuilder` (the delegate) as the argument (very important):

```
def doWithSpring = {       
   CustomResourceLoader.loadSpringBeans(delegate)
}
```

That's it, there is no requirement on users of the plugin aside from creating custom resource files in `grails-app/conf/spring`

Comment: I appreciate you compiling all the above information! Thanks!

Comment: @mowwwalker thanks for reminding me to update this post! see changes above, hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem just a few days ago, with a groovy configuration file that I added into `grails-app/conf`. While this works with other resources (they are copied and available on the classpath), the problem with the groovy file was simply that it was compiled and the class file was included, i.e. not the groovy file itself.

I didn't find any good documentation on how this *should* be done and finally just added it to  `web-app/WEB-INF/classes`. Groovy files placed here will be copied (not compiled) and available on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with custom XML files in Grails 2.1.2.

Having XML resources in `grails-app/conf/spring` didn't work in production environment AFAIR.

To make it working both in development and production environments I finally put the resources into `src/java`. I think you can achieve the same result by putting your groovy files into `src/groovy`.

Comment: src/java should work,  but src/groovy, I believe, would compile the class, I remember reading something about that last night, can u comfirm?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean - all groovy files, including the ones in grails-app are compiled into class files when you run grails war

Comment: I know, but `loadBeans()` reads groovy file, it won't work with class files; when config files reside in src/groovy, it doesn't appear to work (just tested it)

Answer (score 0):

We can import beans from different groovy/xml file in the following way too : -
use the following in resources.groovy -

**importBeans 'file:camel-beans.groovy'
OR 
importBeans('classpath:/camel-config.xml')**

Place camel-beans.groovy along with resources.groovy and provide package as "package spring" for first case, otherwise put it in web app classpath and use the second way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If your resources.groovy is at following path

```
grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy
```

and your camel-beans.groovy is at following path

```
grails-app/conf/spring/camel-beans.groovy
```

then you can reference camel-beans.groovy in resources.groovy file by adding following line in resources.groovy

```
importBeans('file:**/camel-beans.groovy')
```