# Configure Hazelcast in grails project

Tags: xml, grails, config, hazelcast

I have a grails project and I want to configure Hazelcast in it. But I am not been able to do it. I have downloaded the hazelcast and added to lib folder. Then I tried to initialize in resource file

```
hazelcastConfigurer(MethodInvokingFactoryBean){
        targetClass = "com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast"
        targetMethod = "init"
        Config hazelcastConfig = new Config("hazelcast.xml")
        arguments = hazelcastConfig
}
```

It just doesnot compile and throws error

```
[2014-06-04 22:08:25,293] - context.GrailsContextLoader Error initializing the a
pplication: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastConfigurer': Invocation of i
nit method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.haze
lcast.core.Hazelcast.init(com.hazelcast.config.Config)
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'hazelcastConfigurer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception
 is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.init(com.hazel
cast.config.Config)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.init(co
m.hazelcast.config.Config)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1624)
        ... 5 more
```

Is there any blog or site that helps me to configure in grails project?

Comment: Im in the same situation but i started by trying hazelgrails plugin ... does makes sense? ... my goal is just use it for hibernate caching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I configured Hazelcast 3.2 in Grails 2.1.2 app for usage with Spring cache annotations:

BuildConfig.groovy

```
dependencies {
    ...

    compile "com.hazelcast:hazelcast:3.2"
    compile "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-spring:3.2"
}
```

Hazelcast instance configuration, `src/java/spring/hazelcast.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring
                http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-3.2.xsd">

    <hz:hazelcast id="hazelcastInstance">
        <hz:config>

            <hz:map name="myCache"
                    backup-count="0"
                    in-memory-format="OBJECT"
                    >
            </hz:map>

        </hz:config>
    </hz:hazelcast>

</beans>
```

Enabling Spring cache annotations, `src/java/spring/spring-cache.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <cache:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

Wiring it all together - cache manager bean used by Spring cache annotations is configured with Hazelcast instance bean, `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`:

```
beans = {          

        importBeans('classpath:/spring/spring-cache.xml')              
        importBeans('classpath:/spring/hazelcast.xml')

        cacheManager(com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCacheManager, ref('hazelcastInstance'))                       
}
```

Now you can use Spring cache annotations like `@Cacheable` and `@CacheEvict` together with Hazelcast cache:

```
    @Cacheable(value = 'myCache')
    SomethingDto getSomethingDto(Long id) {
        SomethingDto dto = convertToSomethingDto(Something.get(id))
        return dto
    }
```

I usually convert domain objects to DTOs because storing plain domain object into cache can cause problems if some of it's properties are lazily fetched.

Few notes:

- I put Spring XML files into `src/java` because in `grails-app/conf/spring` they were not found in production, see [Load spring beans from custom groovy files in grails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028410/load-spring-beans-from-custom-groovy-files-in-grails-app)
- You can achieve per environment Hazelcast configuration with environment blocks in `resources.groovy`. I use that but for the sake of simplicity I didn't post it here.

Comment: This works :) Thanks. I also want to use hazelcast for sessions. Do you have any idea on that.

Comment: Session data are already stored in-memory of the application server, is there any benefit from storing them in cache?

Comment: I would like to add session data in hazelcast.
Assume that you have more than one web servers (A, B, C) with a load balancer in front of them. 
If server A goes down, your users on that server will be directed to one of the live servers (B or C), but their sessions will be lost.
So we have to have all these sessions backed up in hazelcast if we do not want to lose the sessions upon server crashes. Do you know how to configure it?

Comment: http://www.hazelcast.org/docs/3.2/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#http-session-clustering-with-hazelcast-wm

Comment: I want to use an external hazelcast ... is that possible with this configuration?

Comment: @Biswas see if [this stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35485124/web-session-replication-with-hazelcast-in-grails-hazelcastserializationexcepti) can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Hazelcast version 3.0 it should be `targetMethod = "newHazelcastInstance"` instead of `targetMethod = "init"`.

Comment: This is not an answer. You should remove it