# Splitting resources.groovy (Grails 2.5) to make it modular

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy, grails-2.0

resources.groovy of my Grails project is growing, so I am thinking of splitting it in some logical files that will be easier to mantain. After reading some questions, blogs, i got to know about importBeans or loadBeans. This works well only when application is run using grails run-app. However we I create a war and deploy it on JBoss, the custom bean files are not accessible.
Also tried below with no luck - mentioned here -
 [Load spring beans from custom groovy files in grails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028410/load-spring-beans-from-custom-groovy-files-in-grails-app)

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
  copy(todir: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/classes/spring") {
     fileset(dir:"grails-app/conf/spring") {
        include(name: "datasourceDefinitions.groovy")
        exclude(name: "resources.groovy")        
      }
  }
}
```

I have added datasourceDefinitions.groovy in grails-app/conf/spring. 
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to the Spring bean configuration files are moved into the folder "WEB-INF/classes/spring/"(make sure the file is packaged in the.war) inside the WAR file. As what I did was locate the resource path in resources.groovy.

```
def loadFromFile = { name ->
    importBeans("file:grails-app/conf/spring/"+name)
}

def loadFromWar = { name ->
    def resource = application.parentContext.getResource("WEB-INF/classes/spring/"+name)
    loadBeans(resource)
}
def loadResource = application.isWarDeployed() ? loadFromWar : loadFromFile

loadResource "datasourceDefinitions.groovy"
loadResource "anotherBean.groovy"
```

Comment: Your solution works as expected for me on grails 3.3.6